# Bootstrap Navigation Bar - Brand / Gap issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Need some help here please. I basically need a Navbar which hide the brand and removes the gap beside it when it's over its breakpoint - and to show the brand with the gap when it's under breakpoint. Any idea's please? - thanks in advance. :)

HTML is this within the Navbar toggle - only shows Brand title on small devices or collapsed:

```
<a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">Site Navigation</a>
```

CSS is this:

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 700px ) {
    .navbar .container-fluid, .navbar-collapse {
        padding-left:0;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.in {
        padding-left:30px;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Please post some code. Also the bootstrap docs are quite helpful. Hint: you hide elements with display: none; wrapped in the desired media query.

Comment: Give me a second please Sebastian - will get it for you :)

Comment: This is the CSS:

.navbar-brand > .visible-lg{
   padding-top:0px;
   margin-top: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand > .visible-mg{
   padding-top:0px;
   margin-top: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand > .visible-sg{
   padding-top:0px;
   margin-top: 0px;
}

And HTML is this:
<a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg hidden-mg hidden-sm" href="#">Site Navigation</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is this within the Navbar toggle - only shows Brand title on small devices or collapsed:

```
<a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">Site Navigation</a>
```

CSS is this:

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 700px ) {
.navbar .container-fluid, .navbar-collapse {
    padding-left:0;
}
.navbar-collapse.in {
    padding-left:30px;
}
}
```

That should sort it. :)